# How to run a function after a tkinter window is loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, loaded

If I have a [function](/questions/tagged/function) called `do_stuff()`, how do I execute it ***AFTER*** a [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) window named `root` finishes loading.

Comment: You can use `after` method with some estimated time.

Comment: Explain, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method
You can execute any method after some time.

Comment: While `after` is a viable option, it's worth to notice, that [`Map/Unmap`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M13) event is another option.

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? See  [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the `<Map>` event, the [`<Visibility>`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M14) event is triggered whenever the window/widget becomes visible. By unbinding in the callback, we can make sure the callback is only called once when the window becomes visible.

```py
def callback():
    # your code here
    root.unbind('<Visibility>') # only call `callback` the first time `root` becomes visible

root.bind('<Visibility>', callback) # call `callback` whenever `root` becomes visible
```

Comment: While `<Map>` probably is better for some purposes, I was trying to center the window, and the geometry didn't seem finalized by the time `<Map>` was triggered, so `<Visibility>` was the next best option

Answer (score -1):

When a window is placed on screen in X Windows is has been mapped so the Tk [`<Map>`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M13) event is raised to let your application know that this window is now created and on-screen. If you only want to handle this once after creation then delete your binding the first time your receive the event as it is sent each time the window is re-mapped on screen. ie: minimize and restore events.

Comment: umm... How again?

Comment: The question asked about fully loaded window aka all inner widgets are loaded as well. <Map> is triggered earlier. You can check it by updating the window geometry and then binding window <Map> to print(window.geometry()). The reported value will differ from the required one.